# Closed form of $a_{n+1} = a_n^2 - 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, contest-math

How to find the closed form of $a_{n+1} = a_n^2 - 2$?

Characteristic Root Technique can’t be used here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656171/how-can-we-show-that-b-is-root-of-fx/3656187#3656187

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't see the connection, except when $a_0$ is a root of that polynomial?

Comment: Is it about polynomial?

Comment: We have $a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n+1}}$ therefore $a_{n-1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+a_{n+1}}}$ and we can continue to get something like $a_k=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}\implies a_k=\sqrt{2+a_k}$ and now solve for $a_k$

Comment: You can also show that $$a_n=z^{2^n}+\frac{1}{z^{2^n}}$$ for every $n$, where $z$ is a fixed complex number.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $-2\le a\le 2$, then $a=2\cos t$ for some $t$ and then $a^2-2=2\cos2t$.

If $a\ge 2$, then $a=2\cosh t$ for some $t$ and then $a^2-2=2\cosh2t$.

Therefore if $a_0=2\cos t_0$ then $a_n=2\cos(2^nt_0)$ and
if $a_0=2\cosh t_0$ then $a_n=2\cosh(2^nt_0)$.

This deals with all cases with $a_0\le -2$. If you start with $a_0<-2$
then $a_1>2$ and you soon get back on track....

Comment: Wonderful Solution!

Comment: Thank you very much!